# How to get the same $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] on both localhost and live server

Tags: php, url-routing

So this is the thing, Im building dispatcher class that needs to dispatch http requesd based on Request URI, so Im interesed only in part of URI that comes behind domain.

Now when im working on live server on URI like this:

```
www.domain.com/controller/method/params/
```

REQUEST_URI would return:

```
/controller/method/params/
```

But when im working on local machine i have URI like this:

```
localhost/project/controller/method/params/
```

and REQUEST_URI would return:

```
/project/controller/method/params/
```

So is there an elegant and neat way to tell php to get me only the params I need fromu URI?
It dosent have to be $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], but I need that string the same on both live and local server?

Thanks!

Dispatcher compares current request URI with URI defined in config file. And on live server it matches, but on local machine there is one segment more then on live server.

How could I deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I configure my local webserver to respond on "test.mysite.com" and in hosts file i set test.mysite.com to 127.0.0.1, in that way i better simulate production environments, and i'm not forced to use subpaths in urls

If you use apache webserver, you can simply setup N virtual hosts.

Comment: Yep, Im doing that too on all projects, but this time I should build something that should be tested on localhost, guys joust want to copy project folder in local htdocs folder and navigate it like: localhost/project/ , so I need it joust the way i described in first question. Anyway thanks for answer! :)

Comment: so, since you know your base path, you can replace it ( check if it matches before, so it's valid for production too)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the path from the start of the URL if it exists.

```
$path = '/project/'; // for localhost/project/controller/method/params/
//$path = '/';       // for domain.tld/controller/method/params/

$url = getenv('REQUEST_URI');
if(strpos($url, $path) === 0)
{
    $url = str_replace($path, '', $url, 1);
}
print $url;
```

I haven't tested the above code so stray "/" might mess it up. You can always trim the URL with something like `$url  = trim($url, '/')` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

is that what you want?

Comment: Nope, Im not interested in user IP address, I joust need string like $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], but it needs to be the same on local and live server. It should be on local machine the same like its on live server. Without folder name in URI.

Answer (score 0):

I use the built in *array_shift()* function if localhost is detected.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost') {
    $array_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    array_shift($array_uri);
    $uri = $array_uri;
} else {
    $uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```