# Using PHP's $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] on localhost to get query string - alternative?

Tags: php, frameworks, localhost, url-routing

I'm currently building a simple MVC framework and I've hit a bit of a road block in terms of breaking the URL down on a localhost but also having it work on a live production server as well.

So basically, my localhost URL is:

```
localhost/project/public/controller/action
```

The live version would be:

```
www.example.com/controller/action
```

My initial thought was to just use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] which will work perfectly on a live server but on my localhost it returns:

```
/project/public/controller/action
```

What I need is:

```
controller/action
```

I've had a search around and the only answer I could find was to set up a virtual host which I don't really want to do - this code will be shared between people who may or may not know how to set that up so I want to avoid it if possible.

EDIT: For the record - this is the answer I found - [How to get the same $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] on both localhost and live server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109907/how-to-get-the-same-serverrequest-uri-on-both-localhost-and-live-server?rq=1)

I also can't remove /project/public/ because this folder structure won't always be the same.

So I basically need to get the path up until the public/ part but I can't even use that because the public folder may be called something else.

I know this must be possible because frameworks such as Laravel do it but even looking at the source for that - I can't quite figure it out.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT: Possible Answer**

It's odd how often you have a brainwave as soon as you post something...

I've had the thought that I can just run basename(**DIR**) at my entry point which will give me the folder's name regardless of what it is. I can then use that to remove everything before (in including) the first instance of that folder.

I'll try this out but if there are more elegant solutions out there, I'd still like to hear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also can't remove /project/public/ because this folder structure won't always be the same.

But i assume, you'll always have `controller` and `action` parts? If yes, then do this:

```
$uriParts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$count = count($uriParts);
$controller = isset($uriParts[$count - 2]) ? $uriParts[$count - 2] : null;
$action = isset($uriParts[$count - 1]) ? $uriParts[$count - 1] : null;
```

Try this to get ending string from your `REQUEST_URI` which isn't part of the server path:

```
substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the URL's wont always be composed that way - for example I may have no controller or action and have a route setup for that URL instead. There will also be more parameters after the action so the count won't really cut it I'm afraid. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In that case look at other values in `$_SERVER` - since (i assume) every request goes through bootstrap index.php, you can find it's location and compare it with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` - this will allow you to simply 'cut' all the parts that are in fact folders, not "clean url" parts, i'll try to give you an example in a minute.

Comment: What i meant in previous comment was more or less what you wrote in your `EDIT: Possible Answer` now - that should be a good way to do it, can be done in just one line.

Comment: Try this: `substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])));`